Molecular orbitals in complex aromatic systems
I am a new computational chemistry student currently running calculations to generate orbitals. However, I am finding it challenging to identify the types of orbitals I have.
I would appreciate any advice you have, and I welcome anyone who can help me with this.
I have run a calculation for the following molecule:

and I obtained these frontier orbitals (HOMO and LUMO):

These look like pi orbitals, but I also see density on the oxygen and nitrogen, which confuses me.
Additionally, the orbital in the right image should be an anti-pi orbital since it represents the LUMO, but it doesn't appear to be an anti-pi orbital. I don't see any nodes in the orbitals.
So, I would like to know how I can interpret it.

You have it all backwards. N and O can participate in $\pi$ orbitals all right. The difference between $\pi$ and $\pi^*$ is much less clear-cut than you seem to think. And finally, I see a whole bunch of nodal surfaces in both orbitals.

Pi and sigma and the lot only strictly work as labels on symmetric molecules. Lucian symmetry might work, but description is more difficult. You've picked a somewhat extensive molecule. Maybe you want to start with something smaller: water, ethene, benzene,...

There are several nodes (in white):

Not much different than benzene. All MOs have a node in the plane of the atoms, and as you go to higher energy MOs, more and more nodes perpendicular to that (in case of benzene, the bonding orbitals have zero and one perpendicular node, and the antibonding ones two and three nodes).

In the sketch, a pair of opposite vertical hand-drawn lines defines the position of a perpendicular node.
